# C# Windows Form OnLoad() Event not updating DataGridView.DataSource

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datasource, onload-event

So I have this code:

```
 private void frmSell_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      dgvProducts.DataSource = _data.AllProducts();
 }
```

Where _data.AllProducts() returns a List.
The only problem is that line will only work when outside the _Load() event, for example, it will perfectly work when placed inside a button´s OnClick()

How can I load de products in the _Load event?

Comment: Maybe you forget to attach `frmSell_Load` to `Load` event of the form.

Comment: Have you tried `dgvProducts.DataBind();` immediately after `dgvProducts.DataSource = _data.AllProducts();`?

Comment: `dgvProducts.DataBind()` belongs to `WebForms`.  The question is tagged with `WinForms`.

Comment: Well other lines work inside the _Load event, like Button1.Text = "something" will change the text inside the button

Comment: So you need to post a code to reproduce the problem, because currently based on your descriptions and comments we should just guess something which will be waste of time.

Comment: Possible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sometimes, procedures don't work when called from the constructor. In that case, implement the FormActivate event and call the procedure in the first FormActivate.

Comment: just place it under `InitializeComponent();`